# Why is there a linear relationship between the output frequency of a laser diode and the voltage applied to it?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, laser, cold-atoms

I'm using a tunable laser diode in an undergraduate Rb SAS （saturated absorption spectroscopy） experiment. The product I'm using is the Toptica DLC DL pro, links down below (not an ad). The frequency scan is induced by a triangle wave voltage scan. If frequency isn't linear with voltage, then the time axis on the oscilloscope isn't in a linear correspondence to the frequency. That is, the generated frequency scan won't be a triangle wave but aberrated due to the nonlinear relationship between frequency and voltage. Thus, for the experiment to make sense, it should be assumed that such a linearity exists. Otherwise, I can't deduce the frequency of the absorption line from its time axis value. I might lack common sense in semiconductor physics. I'll be grateful if you can tell me the theoretical explanation for this linearity or guide me to relevant resources.

https://www.toptica.com/products/tunable-diode-lasers/ecdl-dfb-lasers/dl-pro

Comment: I don't believe that the tuning voltage has anything to do with the semiconductor physics of the laser. What the control voltage changes is the angle of a grating which selects the frequency of the laser cavity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunable_laser for a simplified description of these devices. The linearity is then "guaranteed" by the engineering design of the product. If you don't trust it, then you have to calibrate it with a spectrometer, of course.

Comment: @FlatterMann Thanks for your suggestion. I also reckon that the voltage has nothing to do with the voltage applied to the semiconductor. For my model, "it achieves wide mode-hop free tuning by simultaneously varying grating angle, length of the external cavity and laser diode current in optimum synchronization“ . (quoted from Toptica website). So this voltage can be anything. Unfortunately, I don't have the user manual since I'm a student. I guess I just have to trust that the frequency scan is engineered to be perfect triangle wave. The UI design for this product is truly unintuitive.

Comment: Often as part of an instructional lab you're asked to speculate about what sources of error there were in your experiment. This might be a good point to make when you get to that part of the write-up.